# Sequelize include includes the record from the join table

Tags: sequelize.js

Two models have a many to many relationship where a `Product` can belong to one or more `Category`, joined by a table called `CategoryProduct`.

```js
Category.associate = (models) => {    
  models.Category.belongsToMany(models.Product, { through: models.CategoryProduct } )
}
```

```js
Product.associate = (models) => {    
  models.Product.belongsToMany(models.Category, { through: models.CategoryProduct } )
}
```

The association works well, but when I use an `include`, the result set also includes the record from the join table.

The query:

```
let products = await db.Product.findAll({ 
  include: [
    {
      model: db.Category, 
      attributes: ['id'], 
      required: true
    }]
});
```

The response I get:

```
{
    "id": 237,
    "otherProductColumns": "AndTheirValues",
    "Categories": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "CategoryProduct": {
                "id": 9,
                "ProductId": 237,
                "CategoryId": 7,
                "createdAt": "2019-02-22T08:38:26.768Z",
                "updatedAt": "2019-02-22T08:38:26.768Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The response I expect:

```
{
    "id": 237,
    "otherProductColumns": "AndTheirValues",
    "Categories": [
        {
            "id": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the reason for Sequelize to also return the entire `CategoryProduct` record, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Can you add `through:{attributes:['id']}' as well. I don't have running code for now with me to try with.

Comment: If you only need a category id, why not create an attribute in product findAll with a group_concat subquery?

Answer (score 2):

Do you try it and let me know. I found a solution at this [post](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6541)

```
let products = await db.Product.findAll({ 
  include: [
    {
      model: db.Category, 
      attributes: ['id'], 
      required: true,
      through: {attributes: []}
    }]
});
```